# Velocity to Acceleration negative line

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, calculus

Is the velocity line in below 0 is a different acceleration line?

For example from 0 - 6s and from 10 - 17s.
It has the same slope.

[image]

Comment: *It has the same slope.* One has negative slope and the other positive slope, so they aren’t “the same slope”.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Would you be able to adjust the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by velocity line or acceleration line, but they do have the same **magnitude** of slope but different signs. The slope from 0-6 is negative 1 and from 10-17 positive 1. And if the graph above were a velocity vs time graph, the slope would represent the acceleration and the acceleration line which would be on acceleration vs time graph would be a horizontal line at -1 for zero to six and 1 from 6 to 10. And the slope from 6 to 10 is zero and so there is no acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Up to t=6s the accelleration is -1m/s^2 if time scle is s and v scale is m/s. From 6s to 10s a=0 and fro, 10s to 17d accelleration is +1m/s^2